# Construct a "3D" bulding using HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

This question is to broad, I know, but anyway...

How can I achieve the same result as the image below using HTML, CSS and JS (maybe images)? The number of "levels" are unpredictable and every "level" of the building must be clickable, an `<a href="#"></a>`, or something like this.

[image: buildings]

Is that possible?

Comment: "This question is to broad" - Exactly.

Comment: maybe you can use CSS3 transforms in a HTML list, I suggest you to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and update your question with the progress you get

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm not sure if it's too broad to answer. Just like how many people ask "how to call a PHP function from JavaScript", it's sometimes okay to ask about something early in the process to find out whether it's physically possible or not (before, say, devoting a large codebase to the assumption that you'll figure it out when you get there)

Comment: As stated in the Close options **"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format."** By definition this question is too broad.

Comment: @Paulie_D By that definition, "How can I animate a block moving from left to right" would be too broad, merely because there are numerous ways you can do it in JavaScript. Take a closer look at the OP's final sentence; "Is that possible?" If no, that's a valid answer, and I have answered plenty of web-related questions that way; "No, it would be a security risk if browsers let you do this." Several people below have given perfectly appropriate fiddles to solve this problem that are not too long. Please STOP being an obtuse close-voter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I build something with css transformations. Not perfect but i guess you'll see the point. It's using transformations for the roof and the side elements and adds the side elements through a pseudo class.

```css
#stack {
  padding: 10px;
}

.roof {
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #aff;
    transform: translateX(10px) skewX(135deg);
    padding-top: -20px;
}
.level {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #99f;
    margin: 1px;
}

.level:after {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #00f;
    content: "";
    margin-left: 100px;
    transform: translateY(-30px) skewY(135deg);
}

.level:hover {
    background: #f99;
}

.level:hover:after {
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="stack">
    <div class="roof"></div>
    <div class="level">1</div>
    <div class="level">2</div>
    <div class="level">3</div>
    <div class="level">4</div>
</div>
```

Feel free to use links inside of the levels.

Edit: added `:hover` highlighting

Answer (score 2):

You have to play a bit with css transform and pseudo elements.
Just a quick and dirty example:

```css
a {
    display:block;
    width:100px;
    background:blue;
    height: 30px;
    line-height:30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:center;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    position:relative;
}

a:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    background:darkRed;
    height: 20px;
    width: 42px;
    right: -36px;
    top:-2px;
    transform: skew(-45deg) rotate(45deg);
}

div {
    padding:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">one</a>
    <a href="#">two</a>
    <a href="#">three</a>
    <a href="#">four</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible

you can use **canvas** or **SVG**